# Any software mirroring an unencrypted drive resulting in an encrypted mounted drive?

Tags: cryptography

This question was first asked on the cryptography community but was kicked off (not about how cryptography works).

Have your ever heard of a cryptography software that would mount a drive (file/foldernames and content encrypted) reflecting the content of another unenecrypted source drive ? The purpose is to use that mounted drive as a source for online backup (and not online storage) service like Backblaze (not Backblaze B2).
With online storage services, the solution would be Boxcryptor or Cryptomator as ou can map the distant storage area as a local drive (and then drag and drop files you want to upload), but with Backblaze you can't do that.

Comment: Backblaze will only backup locally-connected drives. It doesn't care whether they're encrypted or not, just that they are currently readable & connected locally. There's no way round this [I've tried] ;) I get it to back up my PC as well as my Mac by storing the Win backup **on** the Mac...

Comment: I'd ask again on [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/), Q+A site for system and network administrators, one of the oldest smaller SE sites. Or perhaps Unix+Linux; or perhaps superuser.com (QA site for power users).

Comment: @Tetsujin : yes and no. Backblaze can backup local disks, but also (for instance) Truecrypt volumes pointing to a NAS via iSCSI. What I'm looking for is a software that creates a virtual volume with the same exact folder structure as the source volume, but all names and content encrypted. This way you don't rely on Backblaze "private" key, that you have to send to Backblaze servers once you need to restore your data!